convert VBA to office script
i want to know how to convert this macro to be used with office script,
Sub append_to_next_sheet()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G50").Copy
   
    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" &         Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub

i really have no clue what to do .
script is supposed to take a rang ein Sheet1 then add it to the next available row in sheet 2


The coding logic is simliar to VBA.
OfficeScript doesn't support PasteColumnWidths. But there is a walkaround solution.

Pls try.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const sourceRef = "A1:G50"
    let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    const sourceRng = sheet1.getRange(sourceRef);
    const colCnt = sourceRng.getColumnCount();
    let sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
    // get the first blank cell 
    let objCell = sheet2.getRange("A:A").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up).getOffsetRange(1,0);
    // copy values
    objCell.copyFrom(sourceRng, ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
    // copy col width
    for(let i=0; i<colCnt; i++){
        const colWidth = sourceRng.getCell(0, i).getFormat().getColumnWidth();
        sheet2.getCell(0,i).getFormat().setColumnWidth(colWidth);
    }
}

